# Trying to do sum math using Partition By and Row_Number

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I'm trying to add a few columns to my table and I'm a bit of the way there but not clear why it's failing.  This is an example starting table...

```
Date        Name    Amount
1/2/2015    Andy    148
2/5/2015    Andy    188
2/11/2015   Andy    154
1/15/2015   John    136
2/5/2015    John    176
1/7/2015    John    134
1/19/2015   John    251
2/21/2015   Carlos  120
2/15/2015   Carlos  211
1/8/2015    Carlos  120
1/2/2014    Andy    151
2/5/2014    Andy    281
2/11/2014   Andy    298 
1/15/2014   John    292
2/5/2014    John    134 
1/7/2014    John    281
1/19/2014   John    101
2/21/2014   Carlos  137
2/15/2014   Carlos  108
1/8/2014    Carlos  292
```

I want to take the above table and...

1) Sort by Year, Name, Then Value
2) Based on #1, Add the "Ordered" column which gives a number for each set of Year and Name where Value is set sorted ascending
3) Multiplied column is multiplying Amount by Ordered
4) Sum the multiplied column and a the sum to each set

Result...

```
Date    Year    Name    Amount  Ordered   Multiplied    Sum
1/2/2014    2014    Andy    151      1           151    1607
2/5/2014    2014    Andy    281      2           562    1607
2/11/2014   2014    Andy    298      3           894    1607
2/15/2014   2014    Carlos  108      1           108    1258
2/21/2014   2014    Carlos  137      2           274    1258
1/8/2014    2014    Carlos  292      3           876    1258
1/19/2014   2014    John    101      1           101    2380 
2/5/2014    2014    John    134      2           268    2380
1/7/2014    2014    John    281      3           843    2380
1/15/2014   2014    John    292      4           1168   2380
1/2/2015    2015    Andy    148      1           148    1020
2/11/2015   2015    Andy    154      2           308    1020
2/5/2015    2015    Andy    188      3           564    1020
1/8/2015    2015    Carlos  120      1           120    993
2/21/2015   2015    Carlos  120      2           240    993
2/15/2015   2015    Carlos  211      3           633    993
1/7/2015    2015    John    134      1           134    1938
1/15/2015   2015    John    136      2           272    1938
2/5/2015    2015    John    176      3           528    1938
1/19/2015   2015    John    251      4          1004    1938
```

I have everything but the last column as I keep getting the error...

'Invalid expression near Row_Number'.

SQL for 'Ordered'...

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Partition BY Name, DATEPART(YEAR, Date) ORDER BY Amount ) AS 'Ordered'
```

SQL for 'Multiplied'...

```
 Amount * Ordered AS Multiplied
```

Now I could be thinking of this naively but I thought I could just do add a line like this...

```
sum(Multiplied) OVER ( Partition BY Name, DATEPART(YEAR, Date) ORDER BY Amount ) AS 'Sum'
```

But I keep getting the error mentioned.  Any ideas how to handle?  I'm welcome to hearing other ways of handling the data.  I only care about the last column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your syntax worked, it would produce a cumulative sum.  That doesn't appear to be what you want.

I think you can do what you want with a subquery:

```
select t.*,
        (seqnum * amount) as multiplied,
        sum(seqnum * amount) over (partition by name, year(date)) as thesum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, year(date) order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for this Gordon!  It worked.  I think you meant to label the 5th line as "seqnum" as well.  That threw me off for a sec but then realized what you meant.  I added an order by in the sum line to order the sets by the sequence number but regardless the products and totals were correct.  Thanks so much!